# what module do you recommend for xmlrpc in Perl in cgi script?

Tags: perl, xml-rpc

I am looking for a module in Perl that I can use to respond on remote procedure call in a  serverside script.
Which is the best in terms of quality and easy of use?

Thank you.

From other source, I found RPC::Any::Server::XMLRPC::CGI. (RPC::Any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RPC::XML`](http://p3rl.org/RPC::XML) is okay. See [some real-world examples](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/pingback-proxy/) dealing with  [pingpack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback).